# Dictionary from associations found in list of lists (performance issue)

Tags: python, dictionary

Object: to produce a dict showing which unique values in `base[2:]` (captured in the list `uniques`) are associated with
`base[1]` values (i.e. 5001, 5002 etc.).
The code below works but is too slow for the amount of data I
need to process so I'm looking for a faster way to achieve this.

```
base = [['a', 5001, 1, 4, 8],
        ['b', 5002, 2, 5],
        ['c', 5002, 2, 5],
        ['d', 5003, 2, 6, 7],
        ['e', 5004, 3, 6, 9]]

uniques = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

uniques_dict = {}

for item in uniques:
    uniques_dict[item] = list(set([records[1] for records in base if item in records[2:]]))

print(uniques_dict)

Output:
{   1: [5001], 2: [5002, 5003], 3: [5004], 
    4: [5001], 5: [5002], 6: [5003, 5004], 
    7: [5003], 8: [5001], 9: [5004] }
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: This is Python 2.7. Thank you kindly for the comprehensive answer; your solution is much faster and the commentary is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than loop over all of `records` again and again, invert the loop. Make `uniques` a *set* for fast membership testing, and loop over `records` just the once.

Even better, that set can be handled by the dictionary keys:

```
uniques_dict = {u: [] for u in uniques}

for record in base:
    key, values = record[1], record[2:]
    for unique in uniques_dict.keys() & values:  # the intersection
        uniques_dict[unique].append(key)
```

In Python 3, `dict.keys()` is a [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) which acts like a set. You can create an intersection with that set with the `&` and operator. If you are using Python 2, replace `uniques_dict.keys()` with [`uniques_dict.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) for the exact same behaviour.

Set intersections are fast and efficient; you still need to match each element in `record[2:]` against the key set still, but it is O(N) loop rather than a O(NK) loop as each key test is a O(1) operation independent of K = `len(unique_keys)`.

Demo:

```
>>> base = [['a', 5001, 1, 4, 8],
...         ['b', 5002, 2, 5],
...         ['c', 5002, 2, 5],
...         ['d', 5003, 2, 6, 7],
...         ['e', 5004, 3, 6, 9]]
>>> uniques = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> uniques_dict = {u: [] for u in uniques}
>>> for record in base:
...     key, values = record[1], record[2:]
...     for unique in uniques_dict.keys() & values:  # the intersection
...         uniques_dict[unique].append(key)
... 
>>> uniques_dict
{1: [5001], 2: [5002, 5002, 5003], 3: [5004], 4: [5001], 5: [5002, 5002], 6: [5003, 5004], 7: [5003], 8: [5001], 9: [5004]}
```

If `uniques` is a strict superset of all possible values in `base[*][2:]`, then you don't have to even calculate those up front. Just create dictionary keys as you go along, and use a `set()` on each `record[2:]` list to only handle unique values. The `uniques_dict` values should also be sets to eliminate duplicate keys added:

```
uniques_dict = {}

for record in base:
    key, values = record[1], record[2:]
    for unique in set(values):
        uniques_dict.setdefault(unique, set()).add(key)
```

Now `list(uniques_dict)` is your list of uniques, built as you process `base`:

```
>>> uniques_dict = {}
>>> for record in base:
...     key, values = record[1], record[2:]
...     for unique in set(values):
...         uniques_dict.setdefault(unique, set()).append(key)
... 
>>> uniques_dict
{1: {5001}, 2: {5002, 5003}, 3: {5004}, 4: {5001}, 5: {5002}, 6: {5003, 5004}, 7: {5003}, 8: {5001}, 9: {5004}}
>>> list(uniques_dict)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: If it is not expected to have duplicate elements in each record, taking the intersection isn't necessary. Also, replacing the initialization of `uniques_dict` by `collections.defaultdict(list)` is neater, and will not require knowing beforehand what are the unique elements.

Comment: @RafaelLerm: ah, I think you may be right there. I find `dict.setdefault()` to be more convenient when building a dictionary like this; no import required, exact same output, and you don't later have to assign `None` to the `default_factory` if you need to disable the autovivication.

Comment: You do make a good point. But I normally don't care about what `str` returns on my dictionaries, and I like being able to type  `d[key].append(x)`, and forget about it.

Comment: @RafaelLerm: sure, but being explicit about it with `d.setdefault(key, []).append(x)` can be helpful when you all you are doing is build a dictionary that later on may be expected to throw key errors for missing keys.

Comment: Martijn, thanks to your answer I have just learned about "For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class `collections.abc.Set` are available (for example, ==, <, or ^).". Good to keep in mind.